# Error in passing ID using href of anchor tag in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi i have following directory structure for my HTML files (i have also modified `.htaccess` file to read .html file as .php if needed).

PIC 1: File structure

[image]

PIC2: `localhost/CRM/dashobard.html`

[image]

so in the `dashboard.html` i have table `A` with anchor tag values in column so that user using anchor tag click on link and pass the row id to file `index.html` under `lead` folder.

Problem is that i am not able to send lead id to `CRM/lead/index.html`, so that i display complete information on the new page.

(`loadtable.js` file) part of JS code which load table in `dashboard.html` page is as follows:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {

                    table.last().append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td><a href=./lead/?lead_id="+ value['Lead_Id'] + " </a>" + value['FirstName'] + ' ' + value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Company'] + "</td><td><a href=mailto:" + value['Email'] + ">" + value['Email'] + "</a></td><td>" + value['Phone'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadAddedBy'] + "</td><td>" + "<button class='lead-view' value="+ value['Lead_Id'] + " name=" + value['Lead_Id'] + ">View</button>"+"</td></tr>");

                    i = i + 1;                

                });
```

and File which get the `lead_id` is `CRM/lead/index.html`

```
<?php

    if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] ) {
        echo( 'No parameter lead_id given' );
        exit;
    }

    $lead_id = $_GET['lead_id'];  


    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['State'] == 'Authenticated'){

     $user_id = $_SESSION['User_Id'];

     if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
     {

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
     }   

     $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>     

    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Error i am getting is as below:

[image]

I think `GET` is not working properly.

Comment: You have a parse error. E.g. you wrote some PHP that isn't syntactically valid. It looks like you're using a code editor, so it's surprising that it didn't warn you that you're missing a closing `)`: you have two `(`, and only one `)`. You may want to make sure error reporting is turned on, and teach it that this is a PHP file despite having an HTML extension.

Comment: can i paste all my  code of index.html

Comment: No - the error is obvious, and you already know where it is: line 3 of index.html, where you have two opening `(` but only one closing `)`.

Comment: yes i got that thanks

Comment: Also, if typos were the only problem, then remember that this is not going to help anyone else in the future (because their editor would have told them about them already), and you should probably delete the question. If, after fixing your typos, you still have problems, please update your post.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206424/discussion-between-rinks-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `)` in the `if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] ) {` part.
And you are missing a closing bracket for `if($_SESSION['State'] == 'Authenticated'){` this if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] ) {
```

With:

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] )) {
```

One `)` is missing.

Comment: I've also marked it to close it as a typo

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a closing parenthesis ")" on line 3.

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] )
```

This should be

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] ) )
```